# echo 1 > “runcount.txt” not writing to the file

Tags: server, bash

I am trying to maintain a count of how many times my script evaluates a specific condition to true and want to have its count written to a separate file.

Below are the relevant contents of my file.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
status=$(getstatus) #command which returns status
if [[ $status != *"RUNNING"* ]]; then
        echo 1 > "runcount.txt"
fi
```

However, I don't see 1 written to `runcount.txt` and I also do not see any error on console. Any help to fix this would be really great.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the condition is never satisfied. You can `echo "$status"` before the if statement to check what is happening. - You may want to *append* with `echo 1 >> "runcount.txt"`

Comment: maybe you can do something like this: *echo $(($(< counter) + 1)) > counter*

Answer (score 2):

I assume in `getstatus` you get a string. In that string you want to check wheter the substring *RUNNING* is contained.

I'd recommend you to use grep.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

getstatus(){ echo Im RUNNING now; }

IFS=$'\n'
status=$(getstatus|grep -c RUNNING)
if [[ $status -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo 1 > "runcount.txt"
fi
```

grep seaches for the string *RUNNING*. The option `-c`  just counts how often it appears. So `$status` is now an int. If it appears more than never, it writes 1 into your textfile.

---

Please remove the testfunktion `getstatus()` for your version.

Comment: Hi, here is an idea for another test: `if getstatus | grep -iq -- 'running'; then ...`